# Get the current controller joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I am developping a site in joomla 3.2, i have the same research bar in multiples views with some minor changes, so i created it in an independent php file and i'm using it in different pages .
What i want to do is to change some minor informations depending on which controller is currently active
I tried $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] it works fine but it seems a little messy here is my code

```
function startsWith($haystack, $needle) {
echo $needle;
echo $haystack;
return $needle === "" || strpos($haystack, $needle) === 0;
}
```

then i test like this

```
<?php if (startsWith($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/Immo/administrator/index.php?           option=com_xxo&controller=yy")) { show something ...}
```

is there a better way to know what controller is active for the current page ?
I did not find something similar in the joomla doc

Comment: Use: JRequest::get("controller");

Comment: @RahulK - Incorrect. `JRequest` is deprecated

Comment: Oh yes @Lodder, Use `JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('controller');` i think it is right now..

Comment: thanks my code is better now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('controller'); As simple as that

Answer (score 0):

For me, `JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('controller')` returns nothing. This is how I do it:

```
$controller = \JControllerLegacy::getInstance('whatever');
```

As per fabulous Joomla architecture, you cannot omit getInstance parameter although it is ignored because singleton controller instance is returned.